# Does the GDPR mandate that web sites provide access to cookie settings?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, privacy, gdpr, website

[Cross referenced this question with SO just to get more technical perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202265/do-websites-need-to-implement-custom-cookie-controls-for-the-gdpr-or-are-these-c)

[In this article](https://www.cookiebot.com/en/google-analytics-gdpr/) it says with respect to:

#### Google Analytics and GDPR consent to cookies and tracking:

> Based on a true choice. The user must be able to opt out of all but the strictly necessary cookies and still use the site.
>   Retrievable. The user must have access to their settings and make changes to what cookies they want to accept and reject.

Is it the responsibility of the site to implement this or is this something that the user should be able to do via the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it via the site. I don't know how a browser would let you opt out in the way described.

Also you would not know if the user is using a browser that would let them do this even if most of the popular ones do. Who says the user didn't code their own browser or that they aren't on a computer at work that has the settings disabled?

There could be situations where doing it from the browser is not possible.

Comment: a browser permits rejecting cookies on a site-by-site basis, and permits deleting any existing cookies.

Comment: That does not give them access to their settings though or the ability to know which ones are needed for the site and which ones are not a need.

Comment: Actually it does giove access to the currently saved cookies and their values.  What it does not do is indicate the meaning or interpretation of those, nor which ones are required, or even what exactly each one does. Often this is obvious, but it may be quite cryptic.

Comment: The cryptic part is what I meant. You can't point to every single cookie and say this is needed or not.

Comment: In some cases yes you can, but that wouldn't cover all.

Comment: Even if you could, I haven't even heard of an addon that allows you to filter individual site cookies, let alone a browser feature.  You'd have to expect the user to go through their cookies on every page load to remove the ones that aren't necessary.

Comment: If a site sets a cookie such as `session-id=734b8be7-126d-494e-b10e-1713d613b573` the *same* cookie can be used simulatenously for necessary (CSRF protection, implementing user session) and borderline cases (anonymous statistics) and clearly non-necessary case (tracking users globally for marketing purposes). Clearly any UI provided by the browser cannot select which purposes are okay for this single cookie.